# Android Place Picker does not return to activity

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I have implemented the `PlacePicker` in my app. I have a custom dialog with a pager in it (like 2 tabs). The second pager item has an `EditText` component. On touch of that, I open the placepicker. The issue is that pressing back on the `PlacePicker`, shuts the app instead of going back to the activity from where it started.

This is the code from where the `PlacePicker` starts

```
public void showPlacePicker() {
        try {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(OrganizerMainActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.errorCode, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place selectedPlace = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
                LatLng values = selectedPlace.getLatLng();
                String loc = selectedPlace.getAddress().toString();
                eventFilters.setLat(values.latitude);
                eventFilters.setLon(values.longitude);
                eventFilters.setLocation(loc);
                eventFilters.setUseLocation(true);
                showFilterDialog();
            }

        }

    }
```

The `showPlacePicker` function is called from the Location tab in the dialog in this way

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filter_location, container, false);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_location_progress);
        mInputLocation = (TextInputEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_location_input_text);
        mCheckbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_location_checkbox);
        mInputLocation.setText(eventFilters.getLocation());
        mCheckbox.setChecked(eventFilters.shouldUseLocation());
        mCheckbox.setEnabled(!eventFilters.getLocation().equals(""));
        inputLocationTouchHandler = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mInputLocation.setOnTouchListener(null);
                        mListener.showPlacePicker();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Even when I select a location, the app shuts instead of going back to the activity from where it started.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Any errors in logcat?

Comment: No errors are being thrown in Logcat. Any idea why it should not return to the original activity @VadimKotov?

Comment: check if android:noHistory="true" is written inside your manifest for the caller activity .