# Android PlacePicker does not return selected address

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm using Google PlacePicker in my Android app. I'm able to use it to select addresses. However, it does not return to the caller activity once an address is selected. Instead, I have to press the back button!

This is how I initialize my PlacePicker:

```
/**
 * Add New Address
 */
mNewButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        try
        {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(AddressPickerActivity.this), ADDRESS_CODE);
        }
        catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e)
        {
            int status = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(AddressPickerActivity.this);
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(AddressPickerActivity.this, status, 100).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

and this is how I listen for the result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == ADDRESS_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Google PlacePicker finished");
            // Do Stuff then finish current activity too
            AddressPickerActivity.this.setResult(RESULT_OK);
            AddressPickerActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: I do not get the log message "`Google PlacePicker finished`" unless I press the back button on the place picker! After that everything proceeds as normal, and the actions I want to happen work fine (meaning the address has been picked correctly)

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176021/android-place-picker-does-not-return-to-activity) and the comments suggest that the caller activity might have `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifest. But I checked and it's not. Here's the corresponding snippet from my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AddressPickerActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" />
```

What can be causing this?

### EDIT1:

I also tried explicitly adding `android:noHistory="false"` to the manifest. No change.

Comment: Could you debug and show your `resultCode`, please?

Comment: Since the log statement I have shows, the result Code is for sure RESULT_OK

Comment: Your `AddressPickerActivity` is opening twice because `onTouch` is called twice. Please use `OnClickListerner`for the button.

Comment: Thank you, this actually might be it. I will try it and check if it solves my problem.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OnClickListener` or try to add if condition `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` for startActivityForResult because it happens that PlacePicker is opens twice.

```
mNewButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(AddressPickerActivity.this), ADDRESS_CODE);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                int status = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(AddressPickerActivity.this);
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(AddressPickerActivity.this, status, 100).show();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```